# Create 2 variables which gives me the values in var1_A to var1_E corresponding to the highest values in var2_A to var2_E

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset similar to the one created throuhg the code below (this is a sample of the real dataset).

I need to create two columns (let's call them "ideol_1" and "ideol_2") which gives me the values in "ideolparty" that are correspondent to the two highest columns with similar letters (A:E) in columns "pcv_PR". So, if we have in pcv_PR_A the highest value among pcv_PR_A:pcv_PR_E, the value of "ideolparty_A" should be in column "ideol1" for that row, while if pcv_PR_B is the second highest then "ideol1" should yield the value of "ideolpartyB".

To make the sample data:

```
structure(list(election = c("ARG_2015", "ARG_2015", "ARG_2015", 
"ARG_2015", "ARG_2015", "ARG_2015", "ARG_2015", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", 
"BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", "BRA_2002", 
"BRA_2002", "BRA_2006", "BRA_2006", "BRA_2006", "BRA_2006", "BRA_2006", 
"BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", 
"BRA_2010", "BRA_2010", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", 
"BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", 
"BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", 
"BRA_2014", "BRA_2014", "CHL_1999", "CHL_1999", "CHL_1999", "CHL_2005", 
"CHL_2005", "CHL_2005", "CHL_2005", "CHL_2005", "CHL_2005", "CHL_2005", 
"CHL_2009", "CHL_2009", "CHL_2009", "CHL_2009", "CHL_2009", "CHL_2009", 
"CHL_2009", "FRA_2002", "FRA_2002", "FRA_2002", "FRA_2002", "FRA_2012", 
"FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", 
"FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "FRA_2012", "LTU_1997", "LTU_1997", 
"LTU_1997", "LTU_1997", "PER_2000", "PER_2000", "PER_2000", "PER_2000", 
"PER_2000", "PER_2001", "PER_2001", "PER_2001", "PER_2001", "PER_2006", 
"PER_2006", "PER_2006", "PER_2006", "PER_2006", "PER_2006", "PER_2006", 
"PER_2006", "PER_2006", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", 
"PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2011", "PER_2016", 
"PER_2016", "PER_2016", "PER_2016", "PER_2016", "PER_2016", "PER_2016", 
"PER_2016", "ROU_1996", "ROU_1996", "ROU_1996", "ROU_1996", "ROU_1996", 
"ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", 
"ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2004", "ROU_2009", "ROU_2009", "ROU_2009", 
"ROU_2014", "ROU_2014", "SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", 
"SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", "SRB_2012", "URY_2009", "URY_2009", 
"URY_2009", "URY_2009", "URY_2009"), pcv_PR_A = c(37.08, 37.08, 
37.08, 37.08, 37.08, 37.08, 37.08, 46.4, 46.4, 46.4, 46.4, 46.4, 
46.4, 46.4, 46.4, 46.4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.91, 46.91, 46.91, 
46.91, 46.91, 46.91, 46.91, 46.91, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 
41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 
41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 41.59, 47.9, 47.9, 47.9, 23.23, 23.23, 
23.23, 23.23, 23.23, 23.23, 23.23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
19.88, 19.88, 19.88, 19.88, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 
28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 28.63, 44.7, 44.7, 44.7, 44.7, 
49.9, 49.9, 49.9, 49.9, 49.9, 36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 36.5, 30.62, 
30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 30.62, 31.7, 
31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 39.86, 39.86, 
39.86, 39.86, 39.86, 39.86, 39.86, 39.86, 28.2, 28.2, 28.2, 28.2, 
28.2, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 40.94, 
40.94, 32.44, 32.44, 32.44, 40.44, 40.44, 25.05, 25.05, 25.05, 
25.05, 25.05, 25.05, 25.05, 25.05, 47.96, 47.96, 47.96, 47.96, 
47.96), pcv_PR_B = c(34.15, 34.15, 34.15, 34.15, 34.15, 34.15, 
34.15, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 23.2, 
48.6, 48.6, 48.6, 48.6, 48.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 
33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 33.54, 
47.5, 47.5, 47.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44.06, 44.06, 44.06, 
44.06, 44.06, 44.06, 44.06, 16.86, 16.86, 16.86, 16.86, 27.18, 
27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 27.18, 
27.18, 27.6, 27.6, 27.6, 27.6, 40.2, 40.2, 40.2, 40.2, 40.2, 
25.7, 25.7, 25.7, 25.7, 24.32, 24.32, 24.32, 24.32, 24.32, 24.32, 
24.32, 24.32, 24.32, 23.55, 23.55, 23.55, 23.55, 23.55, 23.55, 
23.55, 23.55, 23.55, 21.05, 21.05, 21.05, 21.05, 21.05, 21.05, 
21.05, 21.05, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, 32.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 31.15, 31.15, 31.15, 30.37, 30.37, 25.31, 25.31, 
25.31, 25.31, 25.31, 25.31, 25.31, 25.31, 29.07, 29.07, 29.07, 
29.07, 29.07), pcv_PR_C = c(21.39, 21.39, 21.39, 21.39, 21.39, 
21.39, 21.39, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.6, 41.6, 
41.6, 41.6, 41.6, 32.61, 32.61, 32.61, 32.61, 32.61, 32.61, 32.61, 
32.61, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29.6, 
29.6, 29.6, 29.6, 29.6, 29.6, 29.6, 16.18, 16.18, 16.18, 16.18, 
17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24.3, 24.3, 24.3, 
24.3, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 23.81, 
23.81, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 18.5, 
18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 18.74, 20.5, 
20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 20.5, 33.92, 33.92, 33.92, 33.92, 33.92, 33.92, 
33.92, 33.92, 33.92, 20.02, 20.02, 20.02, 5.2, 5.2, 14.23, 14.23, 
14.23, 14.23, 14.23, 14.23, 14.23, 14.23, 17.02, 17.02, 17.02, 
17.02, 17.02), pcv_PR_D = c(3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 3.23, 
3.23, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 25.41, 
25.41, 25.41, 25.41, 25.41, 25.41, 25.41, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 6.84, 6.84, 6.84, 6.84, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 
11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 3.1, 
3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 7.43, 7.43, 7.43, 7.43, 
7.43, 7.43, 7.43, 7.43, 7.43, 15.63, 15.63, 15.63, 15.63, 15.63, 
15.63, 15.63, 15.63, 15.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 12.57, 12.57, 12.57, 12.57, 12.57, 12.57, 12.57, 
12.57, 12.57, 5.56, 5.56, 5.56, 4.03, 4.03, 7.44, 7.44, 7.44, 
7.44, 7.44, 7.44, 7.44, 7.44, 2.49, 2.49, 2.49, 2.49, 2.49), 
    pcv_PR_E = c(2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 2.51, 2.51, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 
    21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 
    21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 21.32, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 45.96, 
    45.96, 45.96, 45.96, 45.96, 45.96, 45.96, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5.72, 5.72, 5.72, 5.72, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 
    9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 9.13, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0.4, 
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 
    5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 5.75, 9.83, 9.83, 9.83, 9.83, 
    9.83, 9.83, 9.83, 9.83, 9.83, 5.83, 5.83, 5.83, 5.83, 5.83, 
    5.83, 5.83, 5.83, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 4.7, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 
    5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 3.83, 3.83, 3.83, 3.68, 3.68, 
    5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 5.03, 0.67, 0.67, 
    0.67, 0.67, 0.67), pcv_PR_F = c(1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 1.64, 
    1.64, 1.64, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 
    17.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.33, 5.33, 5.33, 5.33, 2.31, 2.31, 
    2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 2.31, 0.9, 
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 
    4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, 4.38, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.97, 6.97, 6.97, 6.97, 6.97, 
    6.97, 6.97, 6.97, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.18, 3.18, 3.18, 3.47, 3.47, 6.58, 6.58, 
    6.58, 6.58, 6.58, 6.58, 6.58, 6.58, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    pcv_PR_G = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 6.21, 5.25, 5.25, 
    5.25, 5.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 
    1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 1.91, 1.91, 1.91, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pcv_PR_H = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.14, 20.14, 
    20.14, 20.14, 20.14, 20.14, 20.14, 3.91, 3.91, 3.91, 3.91, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.3, 1.3, 
    1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, 1.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.9, 1.9, 
    1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, NA, NA, NA, 5.36, 5.36, 
    1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, 1.62, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), pcv_PR_I = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.85, 6.85, 6.85, 6.85, 6.85, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.37, 
    3.37, 3.37, 3.37, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, 1.32, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4.44, 4.44, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), ideolparty_A = c(2, 10, 4, NA, 5, 5, 6, NA, 0, 8, 
    10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, 
    NA, 10, NA, 1, 3, 2, 9, NA, 0, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 10, NA, NA, 3, 10, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 3, 3, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
    2, 0, 4, 2, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 3, 2, 5, 0, 8, 2, 10, 0, 
    0, NA, 6, NA, 5, 0, 8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, NA, 4, 3, NA, 
    0, 0, 5, NA, 10, 5, 8, 5, 5, 6, NA, NA, 3, 0, 1, 4, 7, NA, 
    NA, 6, NA, NA, 10, 5, 9, NA, NA, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, NA, 6, 
    2, 10, 0, NA, 3), ideolparty_B = c(7.5, 1, 7, NA, 7.5, 8.5, 
    5, NA, 7, 9, 10, NA, 10, 2, 6, 6, 3, 0, 10, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, 3, NA, 9, NA, 10, NA, NA, 4, 
    NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 7, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 10, 10, 0, 10, 9, 9, 10, 2, 10, 10, 10, 9, 6, 
    7, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 7, 5, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 8, 5, 5, 
    10, 8, 1, 2, 0, 10, NA, 7, NA, 7, 5, 6, 5, 2, 8, 10, 6, 9, 
    9, NA, 5, 5, 8, 5, 0, 10, NA, 7, 6, 7, 9, 6, 1, NA, NA, 4, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 8, 1, NA, NA, 3, 5, 
    4, 2, 5, 0, NA, 3, 8, 0, 8, NA, 8), ideolparty_C = c(6, 1, 
    5, NA, 10, 7, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 10, 
    0, 10, NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, 1, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 2, 2, 
    8, 0, 8, 5, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7, 4, 4, 
    10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 1, 0, 3, 10, NA, 3, NA, 8, 
    6, 5, 9, NA, 7, 10, 7, 6, 5, NA, 8, NA, 4, 5, 0, 5, NA, 0, 
    2, 9, 10, 8, 1, NA, NA, 5, 10, 8, 6, 3, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 
    10, 8, 7, NA, NA, 2, 0, 4, 2, 5, 3, NA, 3, 8, 0, 5, NA, 9
    ), ideolparty_D = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9, 9, NA, NA, 3, 
    10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 5, NA, 7, 0, 7, 1, 
    1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 8, NA, 2, 7, 4, 3, NA, 5, 3, 
    1, 3, 5, NA, 2, NA, 8, 4, 5, 4, 1, 10, 10, 6, 10, 6, NA, 
    10, 6, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 5, 5, 2, NA, NA, 4, 9, 4, 
    1, 5, 4, NA, 4, 6, 0, 2, NA, 3), ideolparty_E = c(9, 0, 7, 
    NA, 6, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, 10, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, NA, 3, NA, 
    1, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    2, NA, NA, 7, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 2, 8, 
    4, 5, NA, 5, 6, 4, 8, 6, 3, 5, NA, 5, NA, 4, 8, NA, 6, 4, 
    4, 2, NA, 5, 1, 2, NA, 5, NA, 1, NA, 3, 5, 4, 5, 0, 5, 10, 
    5, 7, 6, NA, 9, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 8, 5, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 5, 5, 6, NA, 
    NA, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, NA, 3, 1, 0, 1, NA, 0), ideol1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-150L), class = "data.frame")
```

The output would be something like this (for some random rows, to see how it would be for different inputs of "pcv" and "ideol":

```
# A tibble: 6 x 13
  election ideol1 ideol2 ideolparty_A ideolparty_B ideolparty_C ideolparty_D ideolparty_E pcv_PR_A pcv_PR_B pcv_PR_C pcv_PR_D pcv_PR_E
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 CHL_2009     10      6           NA           10            6           NA           NA     NA       44.1     29.6     NA       NA  
2 ROU_2004     NA     NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA     40.9     NA       33.9     12.6      5.1
3 BRA_2002      0      7            0            7           NA           NA           NA     46.4     23.2     NA       NA       NA  
4 BRA_2006      0     10           NA            0           10           NA            2     NA       48.6     41.6     NA        2.6
5 CHL_2005     NA     NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA     23.2     NA       NA       25.4     46.0
6 CHL_1999     NA     NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA     47.9     47.5      3.6      0.5      0.4
```

Comment: Can you add something to show a few expected values of your new columns?  Maybe the first 5 rows?

Comment: Question is unclear and would be clearer with sample of desired output. Do `ideolparty_A:ideolparty_E` have any relevance?

Comment: I have just provided a sample of outputs, I think now it is clear . Please check ideol1 and ideol2, the new variables here. They should have the same values of columns in ideolparty_A to ideol_party_E according to the first (ideol1) and second (ideol2) higher values in pcv_PR_A to pcv_PR_E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```
out <- df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("pcv_PR"),
               names_to = "name", 
               values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  arrange(row, desc(value)) %>% 
  mutate(ideol1 = get(paste0("ideolparty_",
                        substr(name[1], nchar(name[1]), nchar(name[1])))),
         ideol2 = get(paste0("ideolparty_",
                         substr(name[2], nchar(name[2]), nchar(name[2]))))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -c(name, value),
              names_from = name, 
              values_from = value)
```

And here is clipping of the result:

```
> head(out %>%
+            select(-contains(c("ideolparty", "row"))))
# A tibble: 6 x 12
  election ideol1 ideol2 pcv_PR_B pcv_PR_C pcv_PR_H pcv_PR_G pcv_PR_A pcv_PR_D pcv_PR_E pcv_PR_F pcv_PR_I
  <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 CHL_2009     10      5     44.1     29.6    20.1      6.21     NA      NA       NA       NA          NA
2 ROU_1996      6      5     32.2     20.5    NA       NA        28.2     6        4.7      3.2        NA
3 PER_2006      0     10     24.3     23.8    NA       NA        30.6     7.43     5.75     4.38       NA
4 BRA_2014      3      8     33.5     NA      NA       NA        41.6    NA       21.3     NA          NA
5 PER_2011      0      8     23.6     18.5    NA       NA        31.7    15.6      9.83    NA          NA
6 SRB_2012      3      6     25.3     14.2     1.62    NA        25.0     7.44     5.03     6.58       NA
```

Comment: It works very well, thanks. Would there be an easy way to do that with many groups of columns like "ideolparty" (let's say we have "ideolparty2_A" to "ideolparty2_E", then "ideolparty3_A", etc. ). Maybe I should've put that in the original question, it is just something that came up afterwards in my analysis.